# Conversion of a Google Form ItemType via Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a form on Google Forms for selling stuff. I know it's not the best solution for this, but my new customer is using it already, so It's not worthy to change now, we are planning to do this further.

What the code does now?

I have set a sheet where I have stored info about the products, like name, price and available qty. When someone submits a response in the form, the script takes the order from that guy and updates the sheet AND the "front-end" of the form. The form is composed by ScaleItem questions, from 0 to 6, unless the available qty is below six. When this happens, the code changes the bounds of the scale so it's not possible to have overbooking.

The problem is:

When the available stock is 1 or 2, I need to change the ItemType, because the ScaleItem requires to have at least 4 numbers (0 to 3).

I've looked on documentation, google and even here and found no solution for switching the ItemType.

This is the code I have so far, **AS IS**. I'm trying to substitute the item, but it's not good solution, because it creates a new column in the form response sheet.

```
var form = FormApp.openById(form_id);
var item = form.getItemById(item_id);
var choices = [];
for (var p = 0; p <= stock; p++) {
  choices.push(p);
}
if (stock <= 2) {
  if (item.getType() === FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE) {  
    item.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(choices);
  } else if (item.getType() === FormApp.ItemType.SCALE) {
    //
    // THIS IS WHERE THE ITEM SHOULD GET CONVERTED TO MULTIPLE CHOICE
    // it is provisionally creating a new item
    //
    // item.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(choices); <= NOT VALID CONVERSION ERROR
    var ii = item.getIndex();
    var title = item.getTitle();
    form.deleteItem(item);
    var new_item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
      .setTitle(title)
      .setChoiceValues(choices);
    form.moveItem(new_item, ii); // this line gets error - still working on
  }
} else if (stock <= 6) {
  item.asScaleItem().setBounds(0, stock);
} else {
  item.asScaleItem().setBounds(0, 6)
}
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: That function [Throws a scripting exception if the ItemType was not already MULTIPLE_CHOICE](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#asmultiplechoiceitem). Instead of trying to change the `Item`, [Remove the old item and create a new one on the Form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It is not possible to convert a `FormApp.ItemType`

If it helps, the minimum required number of options for `ScaleItem` is two and not four (1 to 2).

Otherwise, instead of converting, why do you not declare the item as a different type in the first place? If multiple choice is too bulky for large numbers, maybe you can set the `ItemType` to `List`?

Comment: Yes, I noticed I can go down until 2 with scale item, but it should be able do reach 0 to 1 scale. I did solve it the way you suggested, by using the ListItem type. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a shortfall.  You can do this in the UX but not via the class lib.